# What does the $\ll$ operator signify? This paper says "order" but why didn't they use the big or little Oh notation? is the same thing?

Tags: notation, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds, exponential-sum

https://www.cmi.ac.in/~shreejit/Zeta-Function.pdf

"Our goal in this note is to discuss the behaviour of $\zeta(s)$ in the critical strip $0\leq\sigma\leq1$.   More  precisely,  we  want  to  inspect  how $\zeta(s)$  varies  with $t$,  the imaginary part of $s$, in an infinite vertical strip in this critical region.  One of the most intriguing hypothesis in this direction is the Lindelof hypothesis.  It states that for any $e\gt0$, $\zeta(0.5+it)\ll t^e$, where $\ll$ denotes order" so is that the same as saying $\zeta(0.5+it)\in O(t^e)$  ?

Comment: Could mean... $O(\ldots )$

Comment: I put all of your mathematics into TeX; while there are unicode glyphs for many symbols like zeta, less-than-equals, etc., I (and I think most others here) tend to find the TeX typesetting more legible for mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinogradov used "<<" to mean what Landau (and almost all following writers) writes as $O(...)$

Comment: I'm not sure I would say 'almost all following writers'; the $\ll$ notation in number theory was still prevalent even through the 1980s IIRC.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki OK, maybe I'm somewhat biased, the $O, \Omega, \Theta, o, \omega$ notations are standard in Computer Science.